# Select multiple rows conditioning on ID in R

Tags: r, subset

I tried to select the rows based on their ID. For example, in a data frame called `test`, ID 201 has 6 rows of data, ID 202 has 6 rows of data too, and 203, 204..... etc.

Now I only want to extract 201 and 202 from the dataset, so it should have 12 rows altogether. However

```
out <- test[test$ID==c(201,202), ]
out <- subset(test, ID==c(201,202))
```

only returns three 201 and three 202, which are Row 1, Row 3, Row of 5 8 10 12.

Can anyone provide some suggestions that how I can do this in R?

Comment: In case you're wondering *why* you got what you did, `==` compares element-wise and recycles one vector if it runs out. So it just alternated checking the ID column with 201 and 202. The `%in%` answer is best, but you also could have used `subset(test, ID == 201 | ID == 202)`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You want `%in%`, not `==`.

```
out <- test[test$ID %in% c(201, 202), ]
out <- subset(test, ID %in% c(201, 202))
```

Comment: @MattDowle this is a great candidate for the data.table-intro vignette or perhaps the FAQ! I definitely stepped on this land mine last weekend.