# Subset multiple rows with condition

Tags: r, subset

I have a `.txt` file read into a `table` called `power` with over 2 million observations of 9 variables. I am trying to subset `power` by two rows containing either "01/02/2007" or "02/02/2007". After creating the subset, the RStudio environment said I ended up with zero observations, but the same variables.

**How can I get a subset of the data with only rows containing "01/02/2007" and "02/02/2007"?**

I saw a similar post, but still got an error on my dataset. See link: [Select multiple rows conditioning on ID in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8395716/select-multiple-rows-conditioning-on-id-in-r)

My data:

```
#load data
> power <- read.table("textfile.txt", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, head = TRUE)
#subsetted first column called Date
> head(power$Date)
#[1] 16/12/2006 16/12/2006 16/12/2006 16/12/2006 16/12/2006 16/12/2006

> str(power$Date)
 chr [1:2075259] "16/12/2006" "16/12/2006" "16/12/2006" "16/12/2006" ...
```

My code:

```
> subpower <- subset(power, Date %in% c("01/02/2007", "02/02/2007"))
```

Subset data:

```
> str(powersub$Date)
 chr(0)
```

Comment: Aside from this subset problem, I'd recommend you to convert your character dates to real r Date format before going on with your analysis.

Comment: Also, 16/12/2006 looks like dd/mm/yyyy format, and though ambiguous, your subset criteria is probably in mm/dd/yyyy format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
> subpower = power[power$Date %in% c("01/02/2007", "02/02/2007") ,]
> subpower
        Date Val
1 01/02/2007  14
8 02/02/2007  28
```

(Using power data from @akrun's answer)

Moreover, your own code will work if you use proper name of subset: "subpower" instead of "powersub"!

```
> subpower <- subset(power, Date %in% c("01/02/2007", "02/02/2007"))
> subpower
        Date Val
1 01/02/2007  14
8 02/02/2007  28
>
> str(subpower)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Date: chr  "01/02/2007" "02/02/2007"
 $ Val : int  14 28
```

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing that your dataset may have `trailing/leading` spaces for the column because

```
subset(power, Date %in% c("01/02/2007", "02/02/2007"))
#       Date Val
#1 01/02/2007  14
#8 02/02/2007  28
```

If I change the rows to

```
power$Date[1] <- '01/02/2007 '
power$Date[8] <- ' 02/02/2007'

subset(power, Date %in% c("01/02/2007", "02/02/2007"))
#[1] Date Val 
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

You could use `str_trim` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
subset(power, str_trim(Date) %in% c('01/02/2007', '02/02/2007'))
#         Date Val
#1 01/02/2007   14
#8  02/02/2007  28
```

or use `gsub`

```
subset(power, gsub("^ +| +$", "", Date) %in% c('01/02/2007', '02/02/2007'))
#         Date Val
#1 01/02/2007   14
#8  02/02/2007  28
```

or another option without removing the spaces would be to use `grep`

```
subset(power, grepl('01/02/2007|02/02/2007', Date))
#         Date Val
#1 01/02/2007   14
#8  02/02/2007  28
```

#### data

```
power <- structure(list(Date = c("01/02/2007", "16/12/2006", "16/12/2006", 
"16/12/2006", "16/12/2006", "16/12/2006", "16/12/2006", "02/02/2007"
), Val = c(14L, 24L, 23L, 22L, 23L, 25L, 23L, 28L)), .Names = c("Date", 
"Val"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: Or Maybe they could use the strip.white (hope I remember correct) argument in read.table?

Comment: @beginneR yes, that may be also possible.  But, in another post recently, the OP used all those things and still got these spaces due to some format issues.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct, try reading in the text file with

```
power <- read.table("textfile.txt", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: I made the edits for converting the variables to characters, but ran into the same result. The environment on RStudio says that 9 bs. of 9 variables exist. Subsetting took all the observations out.

Comment: Hmm, I would suggest that link from jazzurro then